# Verifying username and password in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, authentication, networkcredentials

I've an application that's getting gmail email address and password from a database table, and verifying it, before sending any message using those emails, but the following part is returning me an exception, whenever there's any validation error occurs.

```
new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

How can I verify that username and password are correct without throwing any exception at runtime?

Comment: you are sending email through gmail..am I right?

Comment: For sending email through gmail account,account SMTP address should be enabled.Make sure that all the email have enabled there SMTP features in gmail account.

Comment: @Dusk, when asking questions about exceptions, please provide full info including the source line where it is being raised, the type, message and stacktrace. All of this can be obtained by calling `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: @Dusk - can you update your question to show the line where it **actually** raises the exception, not some semi-random line that doesn't raise an exception at all.

Comment: @Dusk:you are still getting the exception after enabling the smtp support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer was provided in order to ascertain the exact nature of the problem as the code originally posted was insufficient.**

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71b57yke.aspx) the constructor doesn't raise an exception - unless you are using the [version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783746.aspx) that takes a [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) for the password.

In that case it raises a `NotSupportedException` if the SecureString class is not supported.

What exception is actually being raised?

Comment: I'm getting "SMTP Exception was unhandled" at send method of SmtpClient class

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71b57yke.aspx) for `NetworkCredential(string, string)` doesn't say anything about exceptions. Mono's [implementation](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#qS7vkPdvHXE/mcs/class/System/System.Net/NetworkCredential.cs&q=networkcredential%20lang%3ac%23&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) doesn't throw exceptions in constructor either.

Do you get an exception when you try to *send* an email?

In either case, wrap it in a `try/catch` block. That's how exceptions are supposed to be handled.
If you're new to exceptions, be sure also to read [Eric's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) on this matter, it directly relates to your question.